# Django: display time it took to load a page on every page

Tags: python, django

In Django, how can I return the time **it took to load a page** (not the date) in **every** page of the site, **without** having to **write in every views.py** a code similar to the following one?

```
start = time.time()
#model operations
loadingpagetime = time.time() - start
```

If using a `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` is the best option.
How would I get the whole page loading time from there, instead of just getting the template loading time?

**UPDATE:**

As the initial question doesn't seem to be clear enough, here is an approach of what would be the **Python version** of what I want to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() 
import time
print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'

start = time.time()

print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<div>HEADER</div>'
print '<div>'
print '<p>Welcome to my Django Webpage!</p>'
print '<p>Welcome to my Django Webpage!</p>'
print '<p>Welcome to my Django Webpage!</p>'
print '</div>'

time.sleep(3)
loadingtime = time.time() - start

print '<div>It took ',loadingtime,' seconds to load the page</div>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Comment: You can write out a placeholder in your template, and then modify it in middleware. However any middleware running after yours could take arbitrary amounts of time, so it's not an accurate count. If you want this done more accurately, do the rewrite in a load balancer, reverse proxy or whatever in front of Django.

Comment: @JamesAylett A answer / example would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to write it out — middleware takes a bit of time to write & test. Good luck!

Comment: Here you go http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/358/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/ Remember that middleware layers are run on the way in, and the way out, in the order they are loaded. So if you put your middleware last, it won't time any other middleware. If you put it first, you'll time them all on the way in *and out*.

Comment: @Jerry I take it as the middleware doesn't suit your need?

Comment: @HieuNguyen Not sure whether I have installed it correctly but I added the code in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and added the HTML mentioned in the `base.html` and it does not work for me.

Comment: OK so, there's an underlying issue here. At the time the template is being rendered, the request is still going on. Elapsed time from request start to when that fragment of the template is rendered is doable, but if a piece of response middleware blocks for 30 seconds, there's no way of including that data in the already-rendered HTML. Like @JamesAylett said, a placeholder that munged by middleware is the closest you're going to get, but there's a *lot* of caveats. See the source of django-debug-toolbar's .middleware module and TimerDebugPanel for a starting point.

Comment: @AdamKG What about a WSGI middleware?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can create a custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) to log this. Here is how I create a middleware to achieve this purpose base on http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/358/ (I modified the code a bit).

Firstly, assuming your project has a name: `test_project`, create a file name `middlewares.py`, I place it in the same folder as `settings.py`:

```
from django.db import connection
from time import time
from operator import add
import re


class StatsMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        '''
        In your base template, put this:
        <div id="stats">
        <!-- STATS: Total: %(total_time).2fs Python: %(python_time).2fs DB: %(db_time).2fs Queries: %(db_queries)d ENDSTATS -->
        </div>
        '''

        # Uncomment the following if you want to get stats on DEBUG=True only
        #if not settings.DEBUG:
        #    return None

        # get number of db queries before we do anything
        n = len(connection.queries)

        # time the view
        start = time()
        response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
        total_time = time() - start

        # compute the db time for the queries just run
        db_queries = len(connection.queries) - n
        if db_queries:
            db_time = reduce(add, [float(q['time'])
                                   for q in connection.queries[n:]])
        else:
            db_time = 0.0

        # and backout python time
        python_time = total_time - db_time

        stats = {
            'total_time': total_time,
            'python_time': python_time,
            'db_time': db_time,
            'db_queries': db_queries,
        }

        # replace the comment if found
        if response and response.content:
            s = response.content
            regexp = re.compile(r'(?P<cmt><!--\s*STATS:(?P<fmt>.*?)ENDSTATS\s*-->)')
            match = regexp.search(s)
            if match:
                s = (s[:match.start('cmt')] +
                     match.group('fmt') % stats +
                     s[match.end('cmt'):])
                response.content = s

        return response
```

Secondly, modify `settings.py` to add your middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # ... your existing middlewares ...

    # your custom middleware here
    'test_project.middlewares.StatsMiddleware',
)
```

Note: you have to add the full path to your middleware class like above, the format is:

```
<project_name>.<middleware_file_name>.<middleware_class_name>
```

A second note is I added this middleware to the end of the list because I just want to log the template load time alone. If you want to log the load time of templates + all middlewares, please put it in the beginning of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list (credits to @Symmitchry).

Back to the main topic, the next step is to modify your `base.html` or whatever pages you want to log load time, add this:

```
<div id="stats">
<!-- STATS: Total: %(total_time).2fs Python: %(python_time).2fs DB: %(db_time).2fs Queries: %(db_queries)d ENDSTATS -->
</div>
```

Note: you can name the `<div id="stats">` and use CSS for that div however you want, but DON'T change the comment `<!-- STATS: .... -->`. If you want to change it, be sure that you test it against the regex pattern in the created `middlewares.py`.

Voila, enjoy the statistics.

**EDIT:**

For those who use CBVs (Class Based Views) a lot, you might have encountered the error `ContentNotRenderedError` with above solution. Have no fear, here is the fix in `middlewares.py`:

```
    # replace the comment if found
    if response:
        try:
            # detects TemplateResponse which are not yet rendered
            if response.is_rendered:
                rendered_content = response.content
            else:
                rendered_content = response.rendered_content
        except AttributeError:  # django < 1.5
            rendered_content = response.content
        if rendered_content:
            s = rendered_content
            regexp = re.compile(
                r'(?P<cmt><!--\s*STATS:(?P<fmt>.*?)ENDSTATS\s*-->)'
            )
            match = regexp.search(s)
            if match:
                s = (s[:match.start('cmt')] +
                     match.group('fmt') % stats +
                     s[match.end('cmt'):])
                response.content = s

    return response
```

I got it working with Django 1.6.x, if you have problem with other version of Django, please ping me in comment section.

Comment: What about the time spend to process other MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES?

Comment: I already mentioned that in the answer above, please read carefully.

Comment: Compiling and running a regex against every single response is a significant performance hit. At the very least, cache the compiled version in the middleware.

Comment: @HieuNguyen How can I make it work with class based views ? The content isn't generated yet and raises `ContentNotRenderedError`.

Comment: @MathieuMarques please check my edit above and try out that fix.

Comment: @HieuNguyen This doesn't seem to be working (I don't have the error anymore though). Doesn't count the queries done nor the time it took (is that even possible with a `ListView` ?) for any of my CBV.

Comment: Hmm it looks pretty okay in my case, I will spend some time (whenever I have free time) to create a totally new test and come back to you later.

Comment: ATTENTION! This implementation simply skips the process_view methods of all following middlewares. This might not be what is expected...

Comment: Great answer, saved. But need to say, instead of `Have no fear, here is the fix in middlewares.py`, you should have `Have no fear, middlewares.py fix is here` :)

Comment: @HieuNguyen Does not work for Django 2.0+. There were some changes to middlewares.

Answer (score 19):

[Geordi](https://bitbucket.org/brodie/geordi) gives you an awesome breakdown of everything that happens in the request cycle. It's a middleware that generates a full call-tree to show you exactly what's going on and how long is spent in each function.

It looks like this:

[image]

I highly recommend it `:)`

Image credit: http://evzijst.bitbucket.org/pycon.in

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong but the first thing I remembered was document.ready and ajax...
I don't think it is the best solution, but it should be quite simple to implement not only in django but anywhere else. 
When you process the request in a view you start timer, and when document.ready is triggered you make an ajax call to stop the timer. 
But I should admit that @Hieu Nguyen is quite brilliant)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show page loading info to your visitors, the answer from Hieu Nguyen will be a great option. But let me also recommend you some good tools.

So if you need this data just for development purposes, take a look at [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). It will attach a nice toolbar with useful statistics for every page, including time it took for DB queries, template rendering and so on.

Finally, if you need professional profiling tools for Djagno, [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/python/django) might be a very good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded middleware.py. In few words, we add some unique text in base template, then replace it in Middleware process_response. This method looks little tricky, but we have generation time closer to true, and we have not problem with javascript. Javascript on client cannot use page headers on firs loaded page, only if create XHR object, then get page.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237632/2837890