# How to set up custom middleware in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-settings, django-middleware

I'm trying to create a middleware to optionally pass a kwarg to every view that meets a condition.

The problem is that I cannot find an example of how to set up the middleware.  I have seen classes that override the method I want to, `process_view`:

```
Class CheckConditionMiddleware(object):  
    def process_view(self, request):  
          
        return None
```

But where do I put this class? Do I create a middleware app and put this class inside of it and then reference it in `settings.middleware`?

Comment: You can follow one of my answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751163/django-display-time-it-took-to-load-a-page-on-every-page/17777539#17777539

Comment: While that is a great answer, you can also follow [the django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter17.html)

Comment: you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751163/django-display-time-it-took-to-load-a-page-on-every-page/17777539#17777539

Comment: @karthikr the link you gave is broken :/

Answer (score 186, accepted):

## First: The path structure

If you don't have it you need to create the **middleware** folder within your app following the structure:

```
yourproject/yourapp/middleware
```

*The folder middleware should be placed in the same folder as settings.py, urls, templates...*

**Important: Don't forget to create the **init**.py empty file inside the middleware folder so your app recognizes this folder**

## Second: Create the middleware

Now we should create a file for our custom middleware, in this example let's suppose we want a middleware that filter the users based on their IP, we create a file called **filter_ip_middleware.py** inside the **middleware** folder with this code:

```
class FilterIPMiddleware(object):
    # Check if client IP is allowed
    def process_request(self, request):
        allowed_ips = ['192.168.1.1', '123.123.123.123', etc...] # Authorized ip's
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') # Get client IP
        if ip not in allowed_ips:
            raise Http403 # If user is not allowed raise Error
 
       # If IP is allowed we don't do anything
       return None
```

## Third: Add the middleware in our 'settings.py'

We need to look for:

- `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` *(django < 1.10)*
- `MIDDLEWARE` *(django >= 1.10)*

Inside the settings.py we need to add our middleware (*Add it in the last position*). It should look like:

```
MIDDLEWARE = ( #  Before Django 1.10 the setting name was 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES'
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     # Above are django standard middlewares

     # Now we add here our custom middleware
     'yourapp.middleware.filter_ip_middleware.FilterIPMiddleware'
)
```

**Done!** Now every request from every client will call your custom middleware and process your custom code!

Comment: Is the path for the file right? Shouldn't it be yourproject/yourapp/middleware instead?

Comment: Yes @tiagovrtr the path should be `yourproject/yourapp/middleware`. I assumed it was pretty obvious but I will update it if that clears you out

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233213/1173647) if you run into: `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

Comment: Added an example for more recent Django versions (_and the fix for the `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`_) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66097539/4779556).

Comment: I don't know.. I spent a lot of time, I had a headache, my eyes want to sleep and I can't create a Question, because I have banned. I tryed all as you say, but it wrotes me "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application". So, I think I need to install custom middleware, but nobody talks about it... :(

Answer (score 22):

### Writing middleware in Django>=1.10

Since Django 1.10, a middleware class must accept a `get_response` argument in its `__init__()` method and provide a `__call__()` method. Although this can be achieved by using the `django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin` when defining a middleware class (*as shown in the [answer by W.Perrin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52041570/4779556)*), creating a class-based middleware in the currently supported versions of Django looks like this:

```py
class CustomMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        """
        One-time configuration and initialisation.
        """
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        """
        Code to be executed for each request before the view (and later
        middleware) are called.
        """
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        """
        Called just before Django calls the view.
        """
        return None

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        """
        Called when a view raises an exception.
        """
        return None

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        """
        Called just after the view has finished executing.
        """
        return response
```

The `process_view()`, `process_exception()` and `process_template_response()` are special hooks, called by Django when processing the middleware, you may define in your middleware class. In the example above, the implemented hooks will do nothing special expect for making sure that Django will call the next middleware to further process the response/request.

### Activating middleware

To activate the middleware component, add it to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in your Django settings.

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Default Django middleware
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # Add your custom middleware
    'path.to.your.middleware.CustomMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: The path in SETTINGS could be a bit more specific, something like `appname.middleware.middlewarefilename.CustomMiddleware`

Answer (score 7):

Just two steps. It works for me with `django2.1`.

**1.Create your own Middleware class.**

There is a good demo from official manual.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

```
    from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

    class MultipleProxyMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
        FORWARDED_FOR_FIELDS = [
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST',
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER',
        ]

        def process_request(self, request):
            """
            Rewrites the proxy headers so that only the most
            recent proxy is used.
            """
            for field in self.FORWARDED_FOR_FIELDS:
                if field in request.META:
                    if ',' in request.META[field]:
                        parts = request.META[field].split(',')
                        request.META[field] = parts[-1].strip()
```

**2.Reference your Middleware class in the `MIDDLEWARE` list of your project `setting.py` file.**

The rule for Middleware reference is the path to your class from the root directory of your project.

For example, in a project named `mysite`,the tree is as follow.

```
├── mysite
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── mysite
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── middleware.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
```

We just add our Middleware class `MultipleProxyMiddleware` in the `middleware.py` file. We get the following reference name.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'mysite.middleware.MultipleProxyMiddleware',  
     ...
]
```

Comment: Tried that but got...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.mymiddleware'

Answer (score 1):

First, middleware is actually the bridge between Httprequest and HttpResponse.

Its scope is normally global, because it bridges the client and server (the HttpRequest must walk the bridge to reach the server and walk the bridge back to the client with the HttpResponse).

You can write a bunch of methods to be run before the request hit the server, or after the request hit the server.

Take the `csrfmiddleware` as an example, the request will first be judged by the middleware whether it's method is POST, if true, then middleware will compare the csrf_token it possessed with the token stored inside the server.

This token is generated when you send the HTML with the form tag, because normally, client will only be able to send POST request through the form server directly send to the client, so server can use this to judge whether this POST is from the form server sent to you, and combined with authentication or authorization, decide whether to send the reqeust to the server or just object the request overall.

So, when you write your own middleware, be clear about what you want to do with the request or response, do you want to add an element in the response?

Like the messagemiddleware did, this new element can be seen as the context django view send or you want to add session, and check the session everytime the client make a request. With this mindset, follow some fixed format, like in this website`https://medium.com/scalereal/everything-you-need-to-know-about-middleware-in-django-2a3bd3853cd6`.

Answer (score 0):

For example, create `middleware` folder with `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `custom.py` in `core/` as shown below: *I referred to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/) and I use **Django 4.2.3**:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-middleware # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom.py
 |-my_app1
 └-my_app2
```

Then, put the code below to `custom.py`:

```py
# "core/middleware/custom.py"

def simple_middleware(get_response):
    print("Here is run only once when the server starts")

    def middleware(request):

        print("Here is run before a view is run")

        response = get_response(request)

        print("Here is run after a view is run")

        return response

    return middleware

class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        print("Here is run only once when the server starts")

    def __call__(self, request):

        print("Here is run before a view is run")

        response = self.get_response(request)

        print("Here is run after a view is run")

        return response
```

Finally, set `simple_middleware` and `SimpleMiddleware` to [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#middleware), then every time you load a django website, the middlewares you set to `MIDDLEWARE` are run:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'core.middleware.custom.simple_middleware', # Here
    'core.middleware.custom.SimpleMiddleware' # Here
]

...
```

Answer (score -2):

It will be helpful in the case of When you know what type of Exception occurs in the views.
From the above I have Created my own Custom class like

```
from .models import userDetails

class customMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self,request):
        result=''
        users = userDetails.objects.all()
        print '-->',users ,'---From middleware calling ---'

        username=request.POST.get("username")
        salary = request.POST.get("salary")
        if salary:
            try:
                result = username+int(salary)
            except:
                print "Can't add"
```

It will be executed when the exception occur in the case of string and integer addition.

You can write Corresponding views for above middleware class