# Passing arguments into partials automatically

Tags: django, django-templates

The problem is the `header.html` partial always contains categories dictionary that is kept on database. Including this partial with arguments

```
{% include "_partials/header.html" with categories %}
```

Every time on rendering partials I need to pass categories dictionary

```
render("index.html", {"flowers":flowers, "categories":categories}) 
render("details.html", {"flower":flower, "categories":categories})
...
```

Is there any solution, that `header.html` partials always contains `categories` dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to setup custom middleware in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-setup-custom-middleware-in-django)

Comment: ^ you can create your own middlewares so that you can include it in your request. There are also [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [custom inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags) for this.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it using inclusion tags.

Created custom tag in the `templatetags/tags.py` file

```
from django import template
from flowers.models import Category
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('_partials/nav.html')
def show_categories():
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    print categories
    return {'categories':categories}
```

Created template for it in the `_partials/nav.html` file

```
<nav>
   <ul>
        {% for category in categories %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'category:detail' category.id' %}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
   </ul>
</nav>
```

At the end, used that tag

```
{% load tags %}
{% show_categories %}
```