# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS to accept local IPs through Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm serving a Django app with Apache.
In Django's settings.py I have `DEBUG = False`, therefore I had to allow some hosts, like: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.dyndns.org', 'localhost']`. This works fine, however I would like to have the server accessible on the local network via its internal IP address as well, like: `192.168.0.x`, or `127.0.0.1`, etc. How could I define `192.*` or `127.*` in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, if I'd like to avoid opening up the access entirely by `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`?

Comment: You may need to write a custom middleware to handle parsing those IPs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @rnevius! I've never written a custom middleware, but I'll investigate in this direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the recommendation from @rnevius, and based on the guidelines from @AlvaroAV in [how to setup custom middleware in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-setup-custom-middleware-in-django), I've managed to solve with this middleware:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class FilterHostMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):

        allowed_hosts = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']  # specify complete host names here
        host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST')

        if host[len(host)-10:] == 'dyndns.org':  # if the host ends with dyndns.org then add to the allowed hosts
            allowed_hosts.append(host)
        elif host[:7] == '192.168':  # if the host starts with 192.168 then add to the allowed hosts
            allowed_hosts.append(host)

        if host not in allowed_hosts:
            raise HttpResponseForbidden

        return None
```

and setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` in `settings.py` no longer opens up for all hosts in an uncontrolled way.

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Nice work! Thanks for sharing your solution. Just a heads up that this middleware should be listed at the top of your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in this case (the other answer you linked to puts the custom middleware at the end of the list). This is mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: Well, I've left as the last one in the list of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, and it works fine. I'd guess that the _first_ in the docs from the sentence 'this middleware must be listed _first_ in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' does not relate to the sequence of the list.

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering what this should be in Django 2.0.dev (In line with @Zorgmorduk's answer)

You need to make the object callable: [django middleware docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/)

1. Create a folder named *middleware* in *yourproject/yourapp/*
2. Create an empty file `__init__.py` inside *yourproject/yourapp/middleware* folder.
3. Create another file, in this case `filter_host_middleware.py`
4. Add this code inside `filter_host_middleware.py`:

   ```
   from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
   class FilterHostMiddleware(object):
       def __init__(self, process_request):
           self.process_request = process_request
       def __call__(self, request):
           response = self.process_request(request)
           return response
       def process_request(self, request):`
           # use the same process_request definition as in @Zorgmorduk's answer
   ```
5. add *yourapp*.middleware.filter_host_middleware.FilterHostMiddleware to your *MIDDLEWARE* in yourproject's `settings.py`; additionally change `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`

You are all set!