# HTTP to HTTPS with health link on Elastic Beanstalk using Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to redirect Http to Https in Django deployed on AWS Beanstalk. Http to Https works fine when I remove the health link from the load balancer. while having link in load balancer the app stops working.

I am using the following config in settings file in the Django project hosted on Aws Beanstalk.

```
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True
HOST_SCHEME = "https://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
```

Comment: whats your load balancer health check configuration.  does your django runs on http or https

Comment: When I remove the health link it works fine and all the links are redirected perfectly fine.

Comment: whats your load balancer health check configuration.

Comment: Health check path: /health
Timeout: 5 sec
Interval:10 Sec
Unhealthy threshold: 5 requests
Healthy threshold : 3 requests

Comment: Are you doing health check via http or https.

Comment: I am trying to do with HTTP

Comment: Do you have any .extensions configured. https://www.vincit.fi/en/deploying-django-elastic-beanstalk-https-redirects-functional-health-checks/

Comment: Yes i saw this blog and tested as well.. didnt work for me

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned, can i assume that you are not using .ebtensions

Comment: yes I am using .ebextension file.

Answer (score 2):

With `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` all non-secure requests will be redirected to https. Non-secure requests - ones done via `http` and with not matched `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`.

Even if your load balancer performs http to https redirect by itself - it is good to have this option enabled in django and simplier (all security options enabled).

---

AWS ALB Health Checks cannot set custom headers. We can exclude requests to certain endpoints from being redirected to https with [SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#secure-redirect-exempt) - `[r'^health/$']`.

---

AWS ALB Health Check requests are done to instance ip. To allow django process  them - ip needs to be added to [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts): `["172.16.2.5", "my.example.com"]`. This needs to be instance private ip, one that will be used by ALB to reach it.

This can be done with:

- Adding instance ip on instance start like in [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031749/django-allowed-hosts-ips-range). It can also be done with custom scripts and environment variables.
- using [custom middleware](https://github.com/mozmeao/django-allow-cidr) which allows adding ip ranges in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and add VPC Subnet range or implement [custom middleware manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222755/12520350)

---

AWS ALB cannot add HSTS headers. If you want to use Strict Transport Security headers - they should be added on app django side. This can be done with setting [SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#secure-hsts-seconds) other than zero.

HSTS headers are only added on responses to secure requests (`https://` or `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` match).

Comment: Have tried by adding IP and also and the other way too. didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried adding health check path to `SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT` (edited answer, had typo in name) and adding instance ip to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: Yes, I applied all these options. but it didn't work

Comment: Have solved my problem. I was inserting public IP in the allowed host but there I must need to put Private IP in the allowed host. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with a middleware (python 3.x):

production settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = ['market.middleware.ELBHealthChecker_middleware'] + MIDDLEWARE
```

ELB middleware:

```
def ELBHealthChecker_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        if "ELB-HealthChecker" in request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]:
            from django.http import HttpResponse
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
        return response
    return middleware
```

Comment: you just need to add private ip of ec2 to in allowed hosts array. It solved my problem in past.

Answer (score -1):

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

These have worked for me in the past.

Comment: I am already using this. It is fine for redirection of requests but when I add health link in Elastic Beanstalk the application health on Elastic Beanstalk gets severe and the app stops working.