# Proper way to retrieve middleware values

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-context

I'm trying to retrieve some loading times per view and displaying it in the page. To do so I'm using a `middleware` and a `context_processor` setup but I can't find the way to retrieve this values to the context of the view.

Here is the example:

- I've added the `middleware` and `context_processor` to the settings.
- middlewares.py (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751163/django-display-time-it-took-to-load-a-page-on-every-page) answer):

  ```
  from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
  from django.db import connection
  from time import time
  from operator import add
  import re

  from functools import reduce


  class StatsMiddleware(object):

      def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
          # get number of db queries before we do anything
          n = len(connection.queries)

          # time the view
          start = time()
          response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
          total_time = time() - start

          # compute the db time for the queries just run
          db_queries = len(connection.queries) - n
          if db_queries:
             db_time = reduce(add, [float(q['time']) for q in connection.queries[n:]])
          else:
             db_time = 0.0

          # and backout python time
          python_time = total_time - db_time

          stats = {
              'total_time': total_time,
              'python_time': python_time,
              'db_time': db_time,
              'db_queries': db_queries,
          }

          # this works fine
          print(stats)

          # replace the comment if found
          if response:
              try:
                  # detects TemplateResponse which are not yet rendered
                  if response.is_rendered:
                      rendered_content = response.content
                  else:
                      rendered_content = response.rendered_content
              except AttributeError:  # django < 1.5
                  rendered_content = response.content
              if rendered_content:
                  s = rendered_content
                  # The following code is commented 
                  # because it can't compile bytes and 
                  # as long as I understand the values comes 
                  # from the rendered template which are the ones I'm interested in getting
                  # regexp = re.compile(
                  #     r'(?P<cmt><!--\s*STATS:(?P<fmt>.*?)ENDSTATS\s*-->)'
                  # )
                  # match = regexp.search(s)
                  # if match:
                  #     s = (s[:match.start('cmt')] +
                  #          match.group('fmt') % stats +
                  #          s[match.end('cmt'):])
                  #     response.content = s

          return response
  ```
- context_processors.py

  ```
  #from django.template import RequestContext

  def foo(request):
      context_data = dict()
      context_data["stats"] = "stats"
      return context_data
  ```
- views.py:

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import render
  from accounts.models import User    


  def myFunc(request):
      users = User.objects.all()
      return render(request, 'index.html, {'users_list': users})
  ```
- index.html:

  ```
  {{stats}}
  <br>
  {% for user in users_list  %}
       {{user}} <br>
  {% endfor %}
  ```

What is the proper way to retrieve these values? The idea is to compare those values later against the cache framework.

Comment: I think you are reimplementing the wheel. Try this django app https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: That is some potentially dangerous middleware. By manually calling the view and returning the response, it skips any view middleware that comes after this one. If you accidentally put `CSRFViewMiddleware` lower in the list, you suddenly have a big gaping security hole in your application.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev It is like the django-debug-toolbar but I need to understand how this works from the very basics

Comment: @knbk I'm glad you mentioned this because I'll be just using it for learning purpose